# problem getting gunicorn.conf file to work in /etc/init

Tags: permissions, configuration, upstart, django

I am trying to configure a gunicorn service. 
The content of /etc/init/gunicorn.conf is something like this:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid nero
set gid www-data
chdir /path/to/webapp

exec virtual_env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/path/to/webapp/project.sock project.wsgi:application
```

If I start the service using `sudo service gunicorn start`, no socket is created and no gunicorn process is spawn (I can find none in the system monitor).

However, if I execute the last line of the configuration file myself in a terminal (dropping the `exec` word), it does work.

Is this a permission problem? I did set the file permissions of all files in path/to/webapp to user nero and group www-data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was myself. Things seem to have changed in ubuntu 16.04. I had to create a `gunicorn.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system/`.

> [Unit]
>   Description=gunicorn daemon
>   After=network.target
>
> [Service]
>   User=nero
>   Group=www-data
>   WorkingDirectory=/path/to/webapp
>   ExecStart=/path/to/webapp/virtual_env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/path/to/webapp/project.sock project.wsgi:application
>
> [Install]
>   WantedBy=multi-user.target

The service can now be started using `sudo systemctl start gunicorn`.